# Is it possible in eclipse to add a set external jar to all projects automatially?

Tags: java

This is purely for personal work. Just messing around stuff so it doesn't really bother me if it could cause problems for others trying to use my code.

Basically what I want to do is allow all of my projects to be able to import a common jar that I always use the same way it can be done with the in built jars in java.

for example

```
import javax.swing.*;
import common.stuff.*;
```

I would like to be able to do this without having to import external jars on every project I make.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No, you need to import the external jars.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it possible to archive with default eclipse settings, but you can do next trick:

1. Go to `Window -> Preferences`
2. Click `Java -> Installed JREs`
3. Find you default JRE, click `edit`
4. Click `Add External JARs`

So you'll add libraries you want to be in every project by putting them to default JRE libraries.